# How to manually write an element of group ring in GAP.

Tags: gap, computational-algebra

Suppose, we consider

> R:=GL(29); (Galois field of order $29$)
>
> G:=SmallGroup(7,1); (cyclic group of order $7$)
>
> H:=Group Ring(R, G); (this generates the group ring).

Suppose that GAP is unable to fetch the list of elements.

Then how can I do the following:

(i) check whether an element is in H or not and how to write that element.

(ii) how to select some element of H, let's say $n$th element.

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3256497/

Comment: i) does not make sense, as the whole elments family consists of elements of the group ring. In ii), what do you mean by $n$-th element? Are you asking how to enumerate the group ring?